# I can't understand the problem in this python code

Tags: python

```
name = input("What is your name?")
len(name)
print(name + " has " + len + " number of letters.")
```

Comment: What do you think `len(name)` does?

Comment: Yes, as @Guy said you are not using `len()` correctly. Try this: `print(name + " has " + len(name) + " number of letters.")`

Comment: @ÁlvaroCuarteroMontilla And after that we move to f-strings: `print(f'{name} has {len(name)} number of letters.')`

Comment: Yes, sorry @Matthias, forgot it! Thank you!

Comment: @ÁlvaroCuarteroMontilla I think it's OK to show the traditional approach first.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `len` is a function, so it is not correct syntax to try to string manipulate this.

A working answer could be to save the length to a variable and then use that variable in your print statement, (like described in the comments above). I would also make this an f-string for more easy use with the variables:

```py
name = input("What is your name?")
name_length = len(name)
print(f"{name} has {name_length} number of letters.")
```

Comment: This will raise `can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`

Comment: Ah! Of course! Let me change this to `str(name_length)`

Answer (score 0):

either

```
l=len(name)
print(name + " has " + str(l) + " number of letters.")
```

or

```
print(name + " has " + str(len(name)) + " number of letters.")
```

this should solve the problem

Comment: This will raise `can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`

Answer (score 0):

best way to do this is using comma instead of spaces in the string and changing the int to string.

```
print(name,"has",len(name),"number of letters.")
```